# how to use upsert logic in informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

how to use upsert logic in informatica with source as flat file and target as teradata. Provided there is no column with distinct values at the target end to be considered as primary key and we do not have access to the unix path for the flat file.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]. This will help to get useful answers.

Comment: Follow @JimHawkins advice. You can also try defining a key on Target Transformation in Informatica.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a column as a temporary primary key in the option available. Open the imported target and in the key type column, make it as primary key

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion,but we actually tried this method and it did't work as there're duplicate rows as well ie. all columns having same values more than once.

Comment: You want those duplicates to be loaded in the target?